# Manually creating VisualStudio 2012 project file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project, thrift

I'm using thrift with Visual C#.

Thrift has option to compile to C#, but, when many C# projects are using thrift, it is tiring adding new and removing old sources generated by thrift one by one - compiling thrift to C# only creates one .cs file per thrift structure.

I thought about writing simple application which would create/update Visual Studio 2012 project file with newly generated thrift files. Is there any tool/library helping with these? Is it safe to get existing project file from empty project, change GUIDs and modify only files list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the classes from the `Microsoft.Build.Construction` namespace this should be relatively easy.

You start with the `ProjectRootElement` which you obtain from opening an existing (method `Open`) or creating a new file (method `Create`). Or you could use a single file as a template and always start from that (it is indeed safe to just set a new GUID).

Then it's just a matter of finding the `ProjectItemGroupElement` containing the source files (i.e. the one having "Compile" items) and add a file to it.

Similarly to set a new GUID, you look for the `ProjectpropertyElement` named "ProjectGuid" and set a new value using `Guid.NewGuid().ToString( "B" )`.

Save the root element and done.

([link to msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.construction.aspx))